Issue with Starting Validator in OpenEthereum: “Account not found for the current chain”
I’m setting up a private test network using OpenEthereum with authorityRound. I’ve created a new account and added it to the list of validators in the spec.json file, but when I try to unlock it for signing blocks, I get the following error:
Account 0x6046…e608 not found for the current chain. You can create an account via RPC, UI or `openethereum account new --chain ./spec/spec.json --keys-path ./nodes/rpc//keys`.
Error: 1

Steps I’ve taken so far:

Created a new account using the command:

./openethereum account new --chain ./spec/spec.json --keys-path ./nodes/rpc/keys/ZEDXION


Added the generated address to the list of validators in the spec.json file:

"validators": {
    "list": ["0x60465d1fa80efbe9776fb1568f821240f545e608"]
}


Configured the node.toml file as follows:

[parity]
chain = "./spec/spec.json"
base_path = "./nodes/rpc/"

[network]
port = 30301
discovery = true

[rpc]
cors = ["all"]
hosts = ["all"]
port = 9545
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", "parity", "traces", "rpc", "personal", "parity_accounts", "signer", "parity_set"]

[footprint]
tracing = "on"
pruning = "archive"
fat_db = "on"


Attempted to unlock the account with the following command:

./openethereum --config ./nodes/rpc/node.toml --chain ./spec/spec.json --unlock "0x60465d1fa80efbe9776fb1568f821240f545e608" --password ./nodes/rpc/keys/ZEDXION/ethereum/password.txt


The spec.json file also includes the account under the accounts section:

"accounts": {
    "0x60465d1fa80efbe9776fb1568f821240f545e608": { "balance": "1000000000000000000000" }
}

Question:
Why is the account not recognized for the current chain, even though it is present in the spec.json file? Is there a specific step I am missing to ensure the account is properly initialized for the network?
